# Use Promises in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I want to use the great Promise interface described on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with my Firefox OS app. But as of Firefox 1.3 (simulator) it doesn't seem to be supported ("Promise is undefined").

Is there a working polyfill whose syntax agrees with the specification on MDN? I don't want to rewrite everything once the real Promises interface is supported by a future version.

This one doesn't work in Firefox OS with Web Workers: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise The reason: It makes use of the "window" global variable.

This one slightly differes from the MDN specification: https://github.com/slightlyoff/Promises - Namely: While the MDN specification says

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { /*...*/ resolve(); /*...*/ });
```

... this polyfill wants to use this syntax (it uses a so called "resolver"):

```
new Promise(function (r) { /*...*/ r.resolve(); /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried the simulator and can just get the promises working on a certified apps. Actually if you get the simulator, and debug any app that comes with the simulator (dialer, camera ...), you'll have a console and there you can inspect the available resources, you'll see how Promises is available.

Also tried on a phone, running gecko master, and it's available at least for privilege apps.

Just an idea that came to my mind, if you go to Tools > Add-ons you can see the simulator as an extension, in preferences it has an option to select your binary, perhaps you could download a latest build from here:

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/b2g/nightly/latest-mozilla-central/

and give it a try.

Comment: Indeed, Promise is supported with certified apps. But with my privileged (that means it has "type: privileged" in its manifest) it does not work. Perhaps it will work, once the app is authenticated by the marketplace etc. Still I don't get, why this shouldn't be available for ordinary packaged apps?!

Comment: Thomas, with latest version of gecko, privileged apps are allow to use Promises, that why I was suggesting to update the B2G binary your simulator is using.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting a simple

```
var window = self;
```

in my Web Worker will make the polyfill from https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise work.

It is an answer, and it at least works around the problem. Still, I'm not happy with it. It seems to me like defining a global window variable in the worker scope will have fatal consequences sooner or later - e.g. when some included JavaScript library tries to check whether it's running inside of a Web Worker etc.

However a fix is in the making: https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/pull/6